How to invoke AWS Lambda via HTTP
Using the AWS Lambda top-level function project template in Visual Studio 2022 I've built a basic lambda:
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;
using Amazon.Lambda.RuntimeSupport;
using Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.SystemTextJson;

var handler = (FramerInput input, ILambdaContext context) =>
    new FramerOutput { framed = $"{input.outer}{input.inner}{input.outer}" };

await LambdaBootstrapBuilder.Create(handler, new DefaultLambdaJsonSerializer())
        .Build()
        .RunAsync();

public class FramerInput
{
    public string inner { get; set; }
    public string outer { get; set; }
}

public class FramerOutput
{
    public string framed { get; set; }
}

It has been uploaded and can be called from the AWS Console and VS AWS Toolkit Extension.
To call it via HTTP I've created a Function URL but I've found no way to invoke the lambda with it, as it always returns the response {"framed":""}.
As an example I've tried via cURL: curl -X GET "https://xxx.lambda-url.us-east-1.on.aws/" -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"inner":"TEST_CURL","outer":"*"}'
As far as I understand the pipeline used to call the lambda via HTTP is different and it's using the API Gateway.
How to fix this code to make it work in both modes?

Its not possible. Lambda url is only https.

Thanks, so how should I build the handler to handle both cases? Even if I guess I might loss any automatic input parameters mapping.

When you invoke a Lambda function using a Function URL, the payload received by the Lambda function is similar to the payload it receives when using Proxy integration with an HTTP API.
The payload structure which is FramerInput in your case will not work as expected when invoking the Lambda function via a Function URL.
So, in order to make it work, do the following:

Add the Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents package to the project.

Change the handler as per below.
using Amazon.Lambda.APIGatewayEvents;

var handler = (APIGatewayHttpApiV2ProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context) =>
{
    var serializationOptions = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
        NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString
    };

    FramerInput input = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<FramerInput>(request.Body, serializationOptions);

    new FramerOutput { framed = $"{input.outer}{input.inner}{input.outer}" };
}



Refer this blog for more detail - Lambda Function URLs - triggering .NET 6 Lambda functions with a HTTPS Request
